# d3.js updating svg.path on drag with euclidean distance

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, euclidean-distance

So I've hacked together a few examples to get something similar to what I want - I've been extending it more and more to learn the library.

I've run into a problem recently - I can't seem to access a path element on drag. I know what I want to do is update the path.value property with the euclidean distance but I can't find where to access or set that property on drag.

I set the distance of the data object on line 264 of this fiddle

```
link = {source: source, target: target, left: false, right: false, value: distance};
```

Where distance is my computed euclidean.

https://jsfiddle.net/p0nqdu1p/2/

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: Reloading the graph with the dataset causes links to scale to their initial source, target length - not the updated length caused by dragging a rectangle they are attached to.

Comment: `this.value = <whatever>`? I don't really get what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I place two nodes and link them, dragging either node will cause the link to scale.

However when I then save that JSON object to re-instantiate the graph later - the link/path length extends to where the link was initially created. It does not update length with drag of the rectangles.

Comment: Ok, so it would be `link.distance = distance`? You've got a lot of code and it's not clear at all to me what happens where. Could you narrow it down to a minimal example please?

Comment: It's fine I resolved the issue - I needed to add an on.drag handler to reset the value property of the link.

Thanks